# how to control the repositories viewing list based on user access permission

Tags: svn

I have successfully setup Subversion repositories using SVNParentPath. But I would like to control the view of repositories list based on user access permission. Example User A only can access repository A and repository B. So when he browse to SVN url he only can see repository A and repository B. Others repositories are invisible for him.

is that anyway to work it out?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout configuration section in the manual at [SVN Manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz). Subversion with Apache is very flexible to customize to suit your need.

Comment: I have used Per-directory access control to control access to the repositories. But it still does not meet my requirement. When user login he still see the full list of repositories under the directory.What I want is he only see those repositories which he can access only...no others